# How do I make multiple check boxes sticky on PHP?

Tags: php, forms, sticky

I am trying to make multiple checkboxes reappear after a failed/incomplete form submission. I am attaching the code below:

```
<div id="left_bottom_box">
    <p> &nbsp <label>Admissions<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="admissions"  tabindex="120" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'admissions') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p> &nbsp <label>Financial Aid & Scholarships<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="aid" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'aid') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p> &nbsp <label>Athletics<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="athletics" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'athletics') echo 'checked';?> /></label></p>
    <p> &nbsp <label>International Student Services Center<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="interntional" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'interntional') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p> &nbsp <label>SEEK Educational Opportunity Program<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="seek" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'seek') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p> &nbsp <label>William and Anita Newman Library<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="library" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'library') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p> &nbsp <label>Baruch Performing Arts Center <input type="checkbox" name="info" value="arts" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'arts') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    </div>

    <div id="right_bottom_box">
    <p><label>Honors Program<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="honors" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'honors') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p><label>Clubs and Organizations<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="clubs" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'clubs') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p><label>Academic Advisement<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="academic" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'academic') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p><label>Housing<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="housing" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'admissions') echo 'housing';?>/></label></p>
    <p><label>STARR Career Development Center<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="starr" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'starr') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p><label>Wasserman Trading Floor/Subotnick Financial Services Center<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="trading" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'trading') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>
    <p><label>Debate Team<input type="checkbox" name="info" value="debate" <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['info'] == 'debate') echo 'checked';?>/></label></p>

</div>
```

I thought this was going to work fine, since it did so with text, but every time I reload the form only the last checked box remains checked. Can someone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Checkboxes dont get passed if they are not checked. Try testing `isset($_POST['Checkbox_name'])`

Comment: Question: how could `$_POST['info']` be all those values at the same time?

Comment: @apokryfos Good point, missed that completely in all the clutter of that code

Comment: Actually all the `<input>`'s are called `info`

Comment: That's why only the last checked box is sent with the form.  Each check overrides the last.  Name them each something different to send them individually.

Comment: It is a general practice for PHP developers to use a name like `name="info[]"` when dealing with groups of checkboxes. That way we can see which values are selected by checking the contents of `$_POST["info"]` which would be an array. Other languages may deal with this differently.